# WordPress P+CDTR Not Working with Thematics

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site that I am building using Thematic and (trying to) [P+CDTR](http://www.joaomak.net/util/dtr/) (Text replacement).

It keeps failing with the error;

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/public_html/mysite/wp-content/themes/thematic/library/extensions/header-extensions.php:7) in /home/public_html/mysite/wp-content/themes/mysite/pcdtr/php/class.php on line 8
```

If I comment out the seesion start in the P+CDTR class.php file I just get a white screen, no errors, no nothing.

Any help or ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `/home/public_html/mysite/wp-content/themes/thematic/library/extensions/header-extensions.php` and `/home/public_html/mysite/wp-content/themes/mysite/pcdtr/php/class.php` and make sure there aren't any blank lines or trailing white space before opening and closing PHP tags near the top and end of your documents.